# Is it possible to scan DynamoDB by nested list property?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have objects in my DynamoDB like this:

```
{
  'id': '2d47218a-9a9b-45a6-acbc-152bc49e93ad'
  'people': [
    {
      'name': 'John',
      'surname': 'Snow'
    },
    {
      'name': 'John',
      'surname': 'Smith'
    },
    {
      'name': 'James',
      'surname': 'Bond'
    },
  ]
}
```

What filter expression should I use to find all objects where at least one person have a name John?

I have tries something like this, but it does not work:

```
DynamoDBScanExpression expression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
                .withFilterExpression("people.name = :name")
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(
                        ImmutableMap.of(":name", new AttributeValue().withS("John")
                .withConsistentRead(true);
        DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB);

        PaginatedScanList<Person> scan = dynamoDBMapper.scan(Person.class, expression);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible on DynamoDB as the object is of complex structure (i.e. DynamoDB terms Map inside a List).

You need both `name` and `surname` attribute values to use **CONTAINS** function to filter the items.

If you have only `name` attribute value, then it is not possible to filter the item.

> CONTAINS is supported for lists: When evaluating "a CONTAINS b", "a"
>   can be a list; however, "b" cannot be a set, a map, or a list.